# MySQL query time intervals

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a big query in MySQL with time intervals, and now the result looks like that:

```
id       time      comment
=========================== 
1        10:00     start
1        10:10     end
1        14:30     start 
1        15:20     end
```

But i need to make it like this:

```
id    start_time   end_time
============================
1      10:00        10:10
1      14:30        15:20
```

Is there any way i can do it?

Comment: Please post your "big query".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, not trivial.  Here is one method:

```
select id, time as start_time,
       (select t2.time
        from t t2
        where t2.id = t.id and t2.comment = 'end' and t2.time > t.time
        order by t2.time asc
        limit 1
       ) as end_time
from t
where comment = 'start';
```

This assumes that the starts and ends are completely interleaved -- that there are never two starts in a row.

EDIT:

If the data is more complex, you can use variables to order the starts and ends, and then aggregate by that:

```
select id,
       max(case when comment = 'start' then time end) as start_time,
       max(case when comment = 'end' then time end) as end_time
from (select t.*,
             (@s_rn := if(comment = 'start', @s_rn + 1, @s_rn)) as s_rn,
             (@e_rn := if(comment = 'end', @e_rn + 1, @s_rn)) as e_rn
      from t cross join
           (select @s_rn := 0, @e_rn := 0) params
      order by t.time
     ) t
group by id, (case when comment = 'start' then s_rn else e_rn end);
```

Comment: Sure you also want to check if id is the same right? `where t.id = t2,id and comment = 'end' and t2.time > t.time` and  also use `order by t2.id asc, t2.time asc` goes for the first query.

Comment: @KidWhoWon Please mark it as answer if this solves your question. :)